# setRepeating of AlarmManager not respond within the time indicated

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-intentservice, android-broadcastreceiver

AlarmManager should be repeated every 1 minute, but repeated every 1, 2, 3 or 4 minutes.

Since the application I throw AlarmManager

```
public class PacienteApp extends Application {
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    AlarmManager gps = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(this, GpsReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, 0);
    gps.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 60, pending);
}
}
```

Since BroadcastReceiver call a IntentService.

```
public class GpsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent gps = new Intent(context, GpsIntentService.class);
    context.startService(gps);
}
}
```

And intentservice execute the task

```
public class GpsIntentService extends IntentService {

public GpsIntentService() {
    super("GpsIntentService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    System.out.println("Intent service ejecutado");
}
}
```

As this occurs in the background, I have a couple of activities running in the foreground.

Comment: How are you measuring this-  in the broadcast receiver or in the intent service?  If in the intent service, if anything is causing the service to run long it would prevent the next one from launching.

Comment: I measure the printing time in the logcat, printing is sent from intentservice.

Comment: Measure from the receiver instead, lets just try to eliminate a potential source of problems.  If the receiver is called every minute, the problem is with your service.  If it isn't, then its with the alarm.

Comment: Also remember that "Note: as of API 19, all repeating alarms are inexact. If your application needs precise delivery times then it must use one-time exact alarms, rescheduling each time as described above. Legacy applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to have all of their alarms, including repeating alarms, treated as exact."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of KitKat (API 19), alarms are inexacted and batched together to preserve battery life by minimizing the number of times the device needs to wake up.

From [the AlarmManager documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) for `setRepeating()`:

> Note: as of API 19, all repeating alarms are inexact. If your application needs precise delivery times then it must use one-time exact alarms, rescheduling each time as described above. Legacy applications whose `targetSdkVersion` is earlier than API 19 will continue to have all of their alarms, including repeating alarms, treated as exact.

For more precision you will need to use [`setExact()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExact(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) and reschedule an alarm every time an alarm wakes up your app. Do so very carefully though, as setting frequent alarms (such as every 1 minute) will dramatically decrease your users' battery life.

From the `setExact()` documenation:

> Note: only alarms for which there is a strong demand for exact-time delivery (such as an alarm clock ringing at the requested time) should be scheduled as exact. Applications are strongly discouraged from using exact alarms unnecessarily as they reduce the OS's ability to minimize battery use.